Trying to add a gitlab repository to my github
I've been trying to add my gitlab repositories to my github account, but I can never finish the process.
What I've done was to create an empty github repository, and set it as a remote for my local gitlab repository. Then, I tried $ git push github main, but this command would never be completed, and I wouldn't receive any error messages, so I don't know what may the problem be.
I received an error message about my git credentials not being the same as the github remote. I tried to fix that (changing the local credentials), but I'm not sure I've done that correctly. I am not receiving this error anymore, though.
I imagine it could be related to the fact that the gitlab repository was created by an institution (my university), or I didn't correcly update my credentials.
I've also tried git mirror, but it would also never be completed.
I tried using $ git push --verbose github main but the only output would be "Pushing to github.com:mariaarabelo/typing-tutor.git" and never further than this.
I've also tried the github option "import repository", but I would get the message "A critical error occured in the Clone Source step of the git migration. Failed to clone git source"
Any ideas about what the problem may be?
Or maybe is there another way I could move my gitlab repository to my github account?

Found out the problem certainly was that I'm a Maintaner in the gitlab repo (I needed to be an Owner to be able to complete the transfer).
